# Unzip and Unrar simultaneously

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code working for an extraction process. First, I made it for zip files but I figured out that I also have rar files. So, I installed the rarfile library and implemented the extraction process.

However, it seems the code raises an exception because the first files scanned are .zip files. That explains, I guess, why I have this error:

```
raise NotRarFile("Not a Rar archive: "+self.rarfile)
NotRarFile: Not a Rar archive: /Users/me/Downloads/_zips/test2/Break_The_Bans_-_Covers__B-sides.zip
```

The extraction code is the following:

```
for ArchivesFiles in chemin_zipfiles :    
        truncated_file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ArchivesFiles))[0]
        if not os.path.exists(truncated_file):
            os.makedirs(truncated_file)
            rar_ref = rarfile.RarFile(ArchivesFiles,'r')
            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesFiles,'r')
            new_folder = os.path.realpath(truncated_file)
            rar_ref.extractall(new_folder)
            zip_ref.extractall(new_folder)
```

And before this code is called, I retrieve all the files with .zip and .rar extensions:

```
chemin_zipfiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory)
             for name in files
             if name.endswith((".zip", ".rar"))]
```

How could I unzip and unrar in the same process and function then? Where am I wrong?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you simply check for extension? Like this:

```
for ArchivesFiles in chemin_zipfiles :    
    truncated_file, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ArchivesFiles)) 
    if not os.path.exists(truncated_file):
        os.makedirs(truncated_file)
        if ext == 'rar':
            arch_ref = rarfile.RarFile(ArchivesFiles,'r')
        else:
            arch_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesFiles,'r')
        new_folder = os.path.realpath(truncated_file)
        arch_ref.extractall(new_folder)
```

Please not a change, where you get a `truncated_file` variable.

Another possibility, which might make things easier later, could be this:

```
funcs = {'.rar':rarfile.RarFile, '.zip':zipfile.ZipFile}

for ArchivesFiles in chemin_zipfiles :    
    truncated_file, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ArchivesFiles)) 
    if not os.path.exists(truncated_file):
        os.makedirs(truncated_file)
        arch_ref = funcs[ext](ArchivesFiles,'r')
        new_folder = os.path.realpath(truncated_file)
        arch_ref.extractall(new_folder)
```

Comment: Hi, That seems pretty simpler. I'm not sure yet (as I just begin to learn Python) to understand the way you used funcs[ext]. However, I receive this error when I'm trying the code : arch_ref = funcs[ext](ArchivesFiles,'r')
KeyError: '.zip'

Comment: Ah yes, I thought `.splitext` returns extension without a dot - not the case. I've updated the answer. In the `funcs` dictionary I keep reference to a function (in python you can pass functions as any other objects), and then in the `for` loop, I'm simply getting that reference to a function and call it.

Comment: Ah ! Indeed, it doesn't return an error now. However, it seems the code only searches and extracts the deepest folder and stops once the extraction is done... Strange, the recursive search and extraction doesn't work anymore. However, I understand the logic you used and I think it shouldn't be problematic...

Comment: Ouch, my bad. I made an indentation error. That's working for the process extraction. Many thanks, that's great :)